# Best way to store timezone-independent time in JPA MySql

Tags: java, mysql, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I can't find a good solution in JPA to store timezone-independent time in a mysql db.

I have a shift table, where I need to store the start and the end time for each shift.

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default  | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL     | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(64)  | NO   |     | NULL     |                |
| start_time  | time         | NO   |     | 00:00:00 |                |
| end_time    | time         | NO   |     | 00:00:00 |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+----------+----------------+
```

So, the start/end times retrived from mysql have to be treated as strings (without applying a particular timezone). But if I store them as varchar(8) I cannot use the following query (without applying any type conversion from varchar to time).

```
select * from shift where ('21:30:00' BETWEEN start_time and end_time );
```

So, I want to preserve the ability to compare them as times.

I tried to model the shift table as following:

```
    @Entity
    public class Shift {
      @Id
      private Long id;

      @Column(name = "name")
      private String name;

      @Column(name = "start_time")
      private LocalTime startTime;

      @Column(name = "end_time")
      private LocalTime endTime;

...
```

The start_time and the end_time are mapped as LocalTime because the LocalTime doesn't store the timezone info. But, Hibernate convert the java.util.Date of each record retrived to a LocalTime applying the system default timezone, as following:

```
    if ( Date.class.isInstance( value ) ) {
        final Date ts = (Date) value;
        final Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( ts.getTime() );
        return LocalDateTime.ofInstant( instant, ZoneId.systemDefault() ).toLocalTime();
    }
```

So, the resulting start/end time is relative to the timezone of the server.

A solution is to store them as integers and split hours from minutes. In this way, the shift table will have four columns: start_hours, start_minutes, end_hours, end_minutes. But it's tedious to make query using them in JPA.
There is a better solution?

**UPDATE**

I have to fetch the current shift using the timezone of the server. So, if I store times as UTC in the DB and then I query them converting the current server time to UTC doesn't work because during the Daylight Saving Time (DST) the server timezone increases by one. So, in the winter the 07:00:00+01 is converted to 06:00:00 UTC. But, in the summer 07:00:00+02 is converted to 05:00:00 UTC.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to SO

It's always better to store dates with **UTC TimeZone** in database and do the conversion on client-side. You can set below property to force JPA To use UTC

`spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`

Hope this  hleps

You can take a look at [this blog](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/)

Comment: Thanks. If i set time_zone to UTC hibernate converts the time used as parameter in the query to UTC. But, when I read from the shift table, hibernate applies the timezone of the server. So, the simpliest solution is to change the timezone of the server, but somethimes in not possible because there are other tested fuctionalites based on the timezone set on the server.

Comment: How you are settling the property?

Comment: As you described in the answer. I have to fetch the current shift using the timezone of the server. So, if I store times as UTC in the DB and then I query them converting the current server time to UTC doesn't work because during the Daylight Saving Time (DST) the server timezone increases by one. So, in the winter the 07:00:00+01 is converted to 06:00:00 UTC. But, in the summer 07:00:00+02 is converted to 05:00:00 UTC.